# Obtaining Linked HTML Text in a Table with RVest

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I'm trying to obtain the game IDs for each game listed in this page.

https://www.chess.com/member/bogginssloggins

Here's what I'm doing now:
First, I'm downloading the HTML with RSelenium and saving it as htmlfile.txt (the table doesn't render unless you use Selenium)
Then, I'm using RVest to parse the HTML.

Here is my code, skipping the RSelenium part

```
library(rvest)
html <- read_html("htmlfile.txt")
GameTable <- html %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]]
```

Unfortunately GameTable doesn't include the game IDs, just the data actually visible in the table. A sample GameID would be something like the link below.

https://www.chess.com/analysis/game/live/9296762565?username=bogginssloggins

These games are very much displayed in the html but I don't know how to systematically grab them and link them to the corresponding rows of the table. My ideal output would be the data in the table on the webpage (e.g. the players in the game, who won, etc but also including a column for the gameID. I believe one of the important things to look for is the "archived-games-link" in the html. There are twenty of those links in the html and twenty rows in the table, so it seems like it should match. However, when I do the below code

```
"htmlfile.txt" %>% read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("[class='archived-games-link']") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
```

I get only 18 results returned, even though when I ctrl+f for "archived-games-link" in the html document 20 results are returned.

Comment: So you have extracted the link? And just want the 9296762565 as an I'd?  Is the URL always the same analysis/game/live/ ? Unlist(str_split(Unlist(str_split (URL, "live/"))[2], "?"))[1]

Comment: No, I haven't extracted the link. I manually extracted that one to provide as an example. Ultimately, what I care about is getting the 20 unique IDs in the table.

Comment: Do you get 18 with .archived-games-result-wrapper ? Does it make a difference if you use a scroll down within selenium and a wait for all elements?

Comment: Didn't think to use Selenium and wait for all elements - right now I'm waiting 2 seconds with Selenium but no scroll down. I'll investigate that.

Comment: I currently only get 3 in the browser for your selector.

Comment: .archived-games-result-wrapper worked great. Thanks QHarr - that's the second time you've solved my problem :D

Comment: I have to wonder if these change over time and that in fact you need a partial class match? I tried to test with a live game page but when I drilled into one of the players (who I can see currently playing!) the website tells me they have no live games. Lol. I'm suspicious due to you observing 20 results in browser for that selector at one point, and at a later time I only observe 3. Ergo.. I would do some testing over time.